# Python: lists .remove(item) but not .find(item) or similar?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

What mechanism is used that allows the built-in function `list.remove` but not simply `list.find`?

If I have a list `l = [a,b,c...]` and want to remove an element, I don't need to know its index, I simply input `l.remove(element)`.  Why is it then that I can't use a similar command to find an element's index or to simply check if it's in the list?

Comment: Lists have `l.index(obj)` and `obj in l` which do exactly what you describe.

Comment: This question isn't aware of the `list.index` method, and instead is looking for `list.find`, so I don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: @AaronHall the question *"Why is it then that I can't use a similar command to find an element's index"* is precisely answered by the duplicate. Also, the OP could use their IDE or [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) to find the `list` methods.

Comment: "Usually 2 similar questions that hold value for different reasons." and direction to close is only for "exact duplicate." http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @AaronHall under those criteria, what value does this question hold?

Comment: People looking for `list.find` won't find the other answer, but they will find this one. I think it's worth keeping around.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that it's not `list.find`, but `list.index`:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l.index('c')
2
```

To test for membership:

```
>>> 'b' in l
True
```

Which is equivalent to (and should be used instead of):

```
>>> l.__contains__('b')
True
```